# How to add a number to a fraction in c++?

Tags: c++, constexpr, fractions

I created a Fraction :

```
class Fraction
{
private:
    int numarator_, denum_;
public:
    constexpr Fraction(int numarator, int denum=1) noexcept : numarator_(numarator), denum_(denum) {}
    virtual ~Fraction() = default;
```

and i want to create a function that add a number to a specific fraction, just like this :

```
int main()
{
    Fraction fr(9,4);
    double res=fr.add(5);
    std::cout<<res;
}
```

i really don't know how to handle it ..as principles i know how it works, but i do something wrong .. if i could add a Fraction f as parameter, it would be nice but i cannot, thats how i have to do it .
I tried to do something like this :

```
constexpr double add(const int number)
    {
        Fraction* fr;
        int numarator2=number* fr->denum_;
        return Fraction(fr->numarator_ + numarator2, fr->denum_); //here i return a fraction and i know i must return a double, the result but i am comfused
        
    }
```

And yes, the constructor and function add must be constexpr

Comment: What is `numitor_`? Why are you declaring a `Fraction` pointer, uninitialized, then accessing it? Are you aware that the correct spelling (at least in English) is "numerator" and "denominator" (if you're using names based on another language, ignore me)?

Comment: Your `add()` function declares a pointer, but never initialises it before using it - so the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: One comment is that you probably don’t want to return a `double` for you add function. Instead return it as a `Fraction`, then create a conversion function like: `operator double() const { return ...}` Maybe also overload math operators instead of using `add( )` or `minus( )`

Answer (score 3):

When you add `number` to a fraction, you need to add `number` units of the denominator:

```
constexpr Fraction add(const int number)
{
    return Fraction(numarator_ + number * denum_, denum_);
}
```

in other words. There's no need to create that temporary `Fraction*` pointer. And note the type change for the function return value.

Comment: Personally I'd write a `double` conversion operator that returned `numarator_ / denum_`. Or another function called `asDouble()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using pointer without initializing.

You should return a `Fraction` not a `double`.

Additionally, you might what to reduce the fraction. If so, you can use `std::gcd()` which is defined in `#include <numeric>` (requires C++17).

```cpp
constexpr Fraction add(const int number)
{
    int newNumetator = numarator_ + number * denum_;
    const int g = std::gcd(newNumerator, denum_);
    newNumerator /= g;
    const int newDenominator = denum_ / g;
    return Fraction(newNumerator, newDenominator);
}
```